# Git: How to change password of credentials used to clone a repository

Tags: linux, git, github

I am working on linux and I clone a private repository using my github account credentials. But over the period of time my password has changed for github and whenever I try to use git pull it is giving me an error 
remote: Invalid username or password.

How can I change the password which I used while cloning the repository for the first time?

Comment: why don't you reset your password from github?

Comment: thanks not an option as I have multiple repositories

Comment: Are your credentials hardcoded in the url? Check .git/config Or hardcoded in ~/.netrc?

Answer (score 1):

You the issue an `git remote -v` and check what kind of auth you are using. I always use git protocol (which uses SSH). You can freely edit those remote urls in ./git/config file. I believe you cloned it using HTTP (or using SSH w/o .ssh key file being present).

If you want to use SSH, you can follow this: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Then you will never need to worry about passwords again.